# How to link shared library in Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to make the following makefile on olaris SPARC

```
CC=/usr/sfw/bin/gcc

INCPATH=/export/home/compkvar/compile/inc
LIBPATH=/export/home/compkvar/compile/lib
SOURCEPATH=/export/home/compkvar/compile/src

.c.o:
        $(CC) -c $< $(INCPATH) -I.


PSOURCE = driver.c

driver : driver.o 
                $(CC) -I$(INCPATH) -L$(LIBPATH) -o driver driver.c -lprivate 

all : driver

clean :
    rm driver.o driver
```

but i got error the following ;

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -I/export/home/compkvar/compile/inc -L/export/home/compkvar/compile/lib -o driver driver.c -lprivate 
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
isinf                               /export/home/compkvar/compile/lib/libprivate.so
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to driver
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `driver'
```

libprivate.so shared library is exist under '/export/home/compkvar/compile/lib' path but it couldn't found:

```
bash-3.00$ pwd
/export/home/compkvar/compile/lib
bash-3.00$ ls -latr
total 14116
drwxr-xr-x   2 compkvar other        512 Sep 12 15:34 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 compkvar other        512 Sep 12 15:34 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 compkvar other     761180 Sep 12 15:43 libprivate.so
-rwxrwxrwx   1 compkvar other    2275492 Sep 12 15:43 libPricingFunctions.so
-rwxrwxrwx   1 compkvar other    1104576 Sep 12 15:43 libprfUtilities.a
-rwxrwxrwx   1 compkvar other    2275492 Sep 12 15:43 libPricingFunctions.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx   1 compkvar other     761180 Sep 12 15:43 libprivate.so.1
bash-3.00$
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're reading the error message wrong - it's not saying that it can't find `libprivate.so`, but that something in that library is referencing another symbol (`isinf`) that it can't find in any of the libraries linked in. As user1969104 points out, you probably need to link in the math library.

Comment: What happens when you try to build `driver` from the command line, without using Make? This doesn't look like a Make problem at all.

Comment: i tried to build driver from command line without using make but it failed too.

Comment: did you ever find the answer? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

isinf is part of math library.  Try including -lm.

```
$(CC) -I$(INCPATH) -L$(LIBPATH) -o driver driver.c -lprivate -lm
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have tried to compile it with -lm flag but it failed again to find "isinf".

/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -I/export/home/compkvar/compile/inc -L/export/home/compkvar/compile/lib -o driver driver.c -lprivate -lm 
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
isinf                               /export/home/compkvar/compile/lib/libprivate.so
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to driver
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `driver'